# AJAX Post Data Formation

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I'm trying to send data to a php file on my server. This is the inside of a function called `send(message)`. I've already used this method to successfully send and receive other data. When I try to use the same method with a different message, it immediately fails with `textStatus="error"` and `errorThrown=""`.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(message));
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: '/web_db_service.php',
    data: JSON.stringify(message),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: doneCallback
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Fail " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    doneCallback(null);
}).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Always " + textStatus + ": " + JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
});
```

The alert at the beginning of the method displays this:

```
{
    "method":"write",
    "className":"Account",
    "id":"test@test.com",
    "object":"
        {
            \"id\":\"test@test.com\",
            \"password\":\"hashedpw\",
            \"first\":\"Tester\",
            \"last\":\"Testing\",
            \"zip\":\"78945\",
            \"phone\":\"11231234\",
            \"children\":
                [
                    {
                        \"id\":null,
                        \"first\":\"Child\",
                        \"middle\":null,
                        \"last\":\"Person\",
                        \"interests\":[]
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

I think it has to do with the formation of the data that's being passed, but I don't know what it is. The php file simply echos the data that's passed to it right now, which again is working for a different, simpler message.

EDIT: 
The problem turned out to be that I was changing the window too soon, without waiting for the message to send and come back.

Comment: You could try `dataType: "json"` instead of "text" if you're sending the data in JSON format.

Comment: What do you send back to the browser, what  your `php` file sends back ?

Comment: @Revent I did text because I'm expecting plain text back from the server. And again, it works with a different message.

Comment: @SheikhHeera the exact php code is `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`